# How can I add array items to DOM one by one?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, iteration, jsx

I want to add items from an array to the DOM one by one not as a batch when the `Array.map` finished its loop.
How can I do that?

```
<div className="gallery-content">
    <div className="content-to-display">
          {iconsToDisplay
             .map((icon, index) => 
                <GalleryItem 
                   key={index}
                   index={index} 
                   item={icon}
                   size={iconSize}
                   isSelected={index===selectedIconIndex}
                   onClick={this.setIconIndex}/>)}
    </div>                
</div>
```

Comment: one by one means? Do you mean after a delay?

Comment: Maybe. i just want to start seeing content from the first item... how can a delay help inside a map function ?

Comment: This would require as many renders as items you have. Is there a reason why you want to delay them?

Comment: There can be up to ~1000 icons and i don't want the user to wait for them to appear in a bulk i just want to add them one at a time...

Comment: there are many way to do so, unsure if they are bad practice. I have one with a setTimeout in chain, so that the items appear one by one or row by row, i ll see if i can share

Answer (score 1):

I think that a convenient way of doing this is to render loading spinner or placeholder first, and then perform hevy data fetching somewhere in [componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount).

This way you won't have to do delays or manually call `appendChild` because even large number of components will be rendered quickly initially.

UPD: see this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0wxkbd9j/1/) for example. First, gallery items are rendered with an initial `loading...` message which is very fast, then I've simulated heavy loading inside the `componentDidMount` which had updated the state with the "loaded" content, and React had successfully rerendered them.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this could be usefull:
https://react-bootstrap.github.io/react-overlays/#portals

> You can think of it as a declarative appendChild(), or jQuery's
>   $.fn.appendTo(). The children of  component will be appended
>   to the container specified.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach might be the following:

Instead of looping inside JSX, you can keep index and items in the state and add an item to the list just before each render. Something like this:

```
state = {
  index: 0,
  galleryItems: []
}

componentDidMount() {
   // manually triggers the first component update
   this.setState({ state: this.state });
}

componentDidUpdate() {
   let galleryItems = this.state.galleryItems
   let index = this.state.index

   // loops until it reaches to the end of list
   if(index < iconsToDisplay.length - 1) {
      galleryItems.push(
         <GalleryItem 
            key={index}
            index={index} 
            item={icon}
            size={iconSize}
            isSelected={index===selectedIconIndex}
            onClick={this.setIconIndex}/>)})

      this.setState({
         index: index + 1,
         galleryItems: galleryItems
      })
   }
}
```

And then, you can have have this list rendered in your `render()` cycle. Something like this:

```
render() {    
   return(
     <div className="content-to-display">
       { this.state.galleryItems }
     </div>
   )
}
```

This way you'd render them one by one.

Disclaimer: I feel like this might work, yet I have not tried the code. I also doubt if it would in any way improve performance. I'm just mentioning it as a possible approach maybe worth giving a go and see.

Answer (score 0):

Tried something with timer. Please see if this helps

[image]

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.icons = [100, 200, 201, 400, 401, 404, 500, 502, 503, 504];
    this.state = {
      iconsToPlot: [],
      message: "Rendering images...",
      pendingCount: this.icons.length
    };

    let timerHandle = setInterval(() => {
      let imgNo = this.icons.pop();
      if (imgNo) {
        let pendingCount = this.icons.length;
        this.setState({
          iconsToPlot: [...this.state.iconsToPlot, imgNo],
          pendingCount: pendingCount
        });
      } else {
        clearInterval(timerHandle);
        this.setState({ message: "Timer stoped as all images are rendered." });
      }
    }, 3000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>
          {this.state.message} Remaining {this.state.pendingCount} images{" "}
        </p>
        <ul>
          {this.state.iconsToPlot.map((key, index) => (
            <li key={index}>
              <img src={`https://http.cat/${key}`} width="150" />
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Play [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/j2581nmmvv)